# Fastest way to insert 100000+ records to mysql in rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I want to transfer info from redis to mysql.

At first, I got the user_id and score form redis.

```
info = $redis.zrevrange("some_info", 0, limit - 1, withscores: withscores)
```

then I need to handle these date:

```
  total_info = info.each_slice(2).to_a.inject([]) do |sum, e|
    sum << {
            id: id,
            name: name,
            rank: rank,
            score: score,
           }
```

`total_info` is an array of size 100000+.

then I need to insert the record of `total_info` to mysql.

I try to create a loop to insert, but i think it is not a good idea.

How to make it? and what is the fastest way?

Comment: The fastest way is to iterate the redis set, write each row to a CSV file and load it with LOAD DATA INFILE

Comment: @e4c5 good idea! I’m trying

Comment: Yeah the best way is to dump the data into a `.sql` file and put that into the db. CSV should suffice; iterating through a loop will take FOREVER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for @e4c5 and @Rich Peck.

I dump the date into .CSV file, then import it to mysql. It is very fast!

```
info = $redis.zrevrange("some_info", 0, limit - 1, withscores: withscores)
CSV.open("temp.csv", "w") do |csv|
  csv << %w(id, name, rank, score......)
  info.each_slice(2) do |e|
      csv << [id, name, rank, score......]
  end
end
```

then:

```
sql = "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'temp.csv'
       INTO TABLE <table_name>
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
       ENCLOSED BY '\"'
       LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
       IGNORE 1 ROWS
       (ia, name, rank, score.....);"
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Active Record Import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) in his [Fastest Version](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import/wiki/Examples#import-using-columns-and-arrays).

Here is an example:

```
columns = [ :id, :name, :rank, :score ]
values = []
infos.each do |info|
  values << [info.id, info.name, info.rank, info.score]
end
Model.import columns, values, validate: false
```